# Olin Lathrop facts

Tags: discussion

Ok, I'm sorry if this is inappropriate, close the post, delete it, ban me for a week, delete my account, kill my cat, burn me alive, but I just couldn't resist...

The question is: Why wouldn't Olin Lathrop deserve his own facts statements ? Chuck Norris has them, Jon Skeet has them, so I see no reason not to apply this to the most reputed man here, right ?

Here are a few:

- Olin built a circuit that could read the contents of the [write-only memory](https://web.archive.org/web/20120316141638/http://www.national.com/rap/files/datasheet.pdf) from Signetics. When he was 10.
- Olin isn't actually active on StackExchange. The posts you see are sent from a PIC18F97J60 programmed by Olin some 4 years ago, simply connected to a DSL router (that he designed).
- On the first day, God said "Let there be light". Olin posted a comment: "You didn't specify the number of LEDs and the supply voltage. *Screw this*."

Do you have some more ?

Comment: @Olin, I'm sorry, but I just had to laugh out loud at that last one!

Comment: On hold already ? I was hoping a few more... Ok, I'm sorry.

Comment: No. If you go to the Jon Skeet Facts page, you will notice that it is locked with a notice saying: "This question exists because it has historical significance, **but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."

Comment: @Dave: I laughed at that one too, and the others.

Comment: The real Olin Lathrop facts: [Interview with Olin Lathrop](https://www.eeweb.com/spotlight/interview-with-olin-lathrop).

Comment: I just saw this. ROFL! :-]] Add this, if you want: **Olin never uses the watchdog. The MCU firmware is already too scared: it will never ever *think* of deadlocking.**

Comment: BTW, from that interview @Nick linked to it seems also that... **Olin never flushes the toilet alone. Every time he flushes, any toilet in a 100m radius automatically develops a temporary embedded AI that forces it to flush at the same time.**

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I like the watchdog one. But I'm afraid the bump from the editing will remind people of this post, which will lead to its deletion... Oh, nevermind, I'm doing it anyway.

Comment: @clabacchio I guess the rollback means: "Just leave this post alone and let everyone forget about it"... All right, then, I won't touch it again.

Comment: The post had been flagged, as fun as it is (and I agree) it should be left alone to avoid creating a precedent. Perhaps you could try to get it reopened

Comment: In 1978 Olin was the creator of the first portable computer which was named after him. Unfortunately people constantly misspelled and miss-pronounced his name.

Comment: @ChristianChapman The behavior of having fun is disgusting? You do realize that at no point here the intention is to make fun at the expense of someone, and that those jokes actually glorify Olin's contributions, more than anything else? Proof is the comment he himself made on this very post. On my side, what I find bad is the tendency to get offended by things that aren't meant to be offensive. It ruins everything. Anyway...